# javascript left hand side error

Tags: javascript

I'm a complete noob when it comes to javascript but I am not getting why I'm getting the reference error when I try an "play" my heads or tails game.

```
document.write("

<button type='button' onclick='kop()'>kop</button></br>
<button type='button' onclick='munt()'>munt</button>
</br></br></br>
<button type='button' onclick='score()'>Score</button>

<p id='ww'></p>
<p id='ll'></p>
</br></br></br>
<p id='wi'></p>
<p id='lo'></p>

");

function kop(){
var keuze="kop";

var out=Math.floor(Math.random()*10+1);

if(out>5){
alert("het is inderdaad "+keuze+"!");
document.getElementById("ww")=document.getElementById("ww")+" ";

}else{
alert("het was munt!!");
document.getElementById("ll")=document.getElementById("ll")+" ";

}
}

function munt(){
var keuze="munt";

var out=Math.floor(Math.random()*10+1);

if(out<=5){
alert("het is inderdaad "+keuze+"!");

document.getElementById("ww")=document.getElementById("ww")+" ";

}else{
alert("het was kop!!");
document.getElementById("ll")=document.getElementById("ll")+" ";

}
};

function score(){

document.getElementById("wi")=document.getElementById("ww").length ;

document.getElementById("lo")=document.getElementById("ll").length;

}
```

Comment: And the error you are getting is...  ???

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Read this on how to properly ask qustions here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: That JS will throw *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL*, not a reference error.

Answer (score 0):

replace LHS from document.getElementById() to

```
document.getElementById(<id>).innerHTML
```

for example, change

```
document.getElementById("ww")=document.getElementById("ww")+" ";
```

to

```
document.getElementById("ww").innerHTML=document.getElementById("ww")+" ";
```